# SQL query very slow. How to improve without indexes?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I need to get data from multiple tables with a single query which gives approximately 10600 results (rows). The problem is that the query takes a very long time to execute. Like.. very long time.. 90 sec.

Is there any way I could improve the query without adding indexes? The tables are updated constantly (rows inserted, updated, deleted).

Here is the query:

```
SELECT 
    t1.ID
    , t1.ref
    , t1.type
    , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t3.name) AS parish
    , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t2.village) AS village
    , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t2.code) AS code
    , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t4.year) AS year
FROM table1 t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t2.teade_ID = t1.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 AS t3 ON t2.parish_ID = t3.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table4 AS t4 ON t4.teade_ID = t1.ID
GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.ref, t1.type
ORDER BY t1.ID DESC
```

Any help is very much appriciated!

Comment: Are you sure the inserting/updating/deleting overhead would be too much for you? Is this the case for all 4 tables? Often people overestimate this effect, especially with nightly/weekly index maintenance. Still if your certain, for a good answer you might want to add information about the relative table sizes, column count & types.

Comment: Are you sure don't want use or add index? because that's what indexes are built for. Especially when you have huge data.

Comment: How long will the output of your `GROUP_CONCAT()` fields be ? If they become lengthy (for those 10600 rows) then you might have a memory problem (not enough cache to keep complete output in memory, which causes the need for temp tables....)

Comment: You need the indexes if you're going to do JOINs.

Comment: Any idea why when I try creating indexes I get the result "MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)."? Empty result set.

Answer (score 0):

Aggregate *before* joining:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.ref, t1.type,
       t2.villages, t2.codes,
       t3.villages, t4.years
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT t2.teade_ID, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.code) AS codes,
             GROUP_CONCAT(t2.village) as villages
      FROM table2 t2
      GROUP BY t2.teade_ID
     ) t2
     ON t2.teade_ID = t1.ID LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT t2.teade_ID, GROUP_CONCAT(t3.village) as villages
      FROM table2 t2 JOIN
           table3 t3
           ON t2.parish_ID = t3.ID
      GROUP BY t2.teade_ID
     ) t3
     ON t3.teade_id = t.id LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t4.year) AS year
      FROM table4 t4
      GROUP BY t2.teade_ID
     ) t4
     ON t4.teade_ID = t1.ID
ORDER BY t1.ID DESC;
```

You might still need `DISTINCT` in the `GROUP_CONCAT()`.  It is not clear from your question if this is still needed.

Why is this faster?  Your version is generating a cross product of all the tables for each `ID` -- potentially greatly multiplying the size of the data.  More data makes the `GROUP BY` slower.

Also note that there is no aggregation in the outer query.

Comment: Trying your query gives me the following error: "Unknown column 't2.teade_ID' in 'group statement'" even though the column does exist. Any idea why would it say so?

Answer (score 0):

**Plan A - Make the GROUP BY and ORDER BY match:**

Normally an index is primarily used for the `WHERE` clause.  But there is no filtering, so the index can move on to `GROUP BY`.  What index(es) do you have?  If you have `PRIMARY KEY(id)`, then changing to simply this is likely to work:

```
GROUP BY t1.ID
ORDER BY t1.ID DESC
```

If there is trouble with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`, you *might* need

```
GROUP BY t1.ID,      t1.ref,      t1.type
ORDER BY t1.ID DESC, t1.ref DESC, t1.type DESC
```

In either case note how the GROUP BY and ORDER BY "match" each other.  With this (unlike what you have), both clauses can be done in a single step.  Hence no need to gather all the rows, do the grouping, then sort.  Getting rid of the sort is where you would gain speed.

**Plan B - Delay the access to the troublesome `ref` and `type`:**

```
SELECT ID, t1x.ref, t1x.type
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            t1.ID
            , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t3.name) AS parish
            , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t2.village) AS village
            , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t2.code) AS code
            , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t4.year) AS year
        FROM table1 t1
            LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t2.teade_ID = t1.ID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 AS t3 ON t2.parish_ID = t3.ID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN table4 AS t4 ON t4.teade_ID = t1.ID
        GROUP BY t1.ID
         ) x
    JOIN t1 AS t1x  USING(ID)
    ORDER BY t1.ID DESC
```

`ORDER BY` is ignored in the derived table; `GROUP BY` is not necessary in the outer table.

**Plan C - Get rid of the GROUP BY on the assumption that `ID` is the PK:**

```
SELECT  ID, ref, type
        ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t3.name)
                FROM t3 WHERE t3.ID = t1.ID ) AS parish,
        ( ... ) AS ...,
        ( ... ) AS ...,
        ( ... ) AS ...
    FROM t1
    ORDER BY ID DESC
```

The subqueries have the same semantics as your original `LEFT JOIN`.

Your original query suffers from "explode-implode".  First the JOINs gather all the parishes, etc, leading to a big intermediate table.  Then the grouping shrinks it back to only what you needed.  Plan C avoids that explode-implode, and hence the GROUP BY.

Furthermore, there won't be a sort because it can simply scan the table in reverse order.